# COUNT en postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

En el ejemplo mostrado en el siguiente enlace https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp, ¿cómo debería ser la consulta que realicemos para que el resultado tenga 2 columnas, siendo la primera los 21 países y siendo la segunda el número de clientes de cada país?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, traslada a la pregunta el escenario real  de tu problema, indicando cómo tienes organizadas las tablas. E indica lo que has intentado. Tu pregunta parece pedir algo como *hagan esto por mi*. Este no es el objetivo de este sitio, sino ayudar a resolver problemas concretos basados en código concreto. ¿Intentaste algo, investigaste algo? A raíz de eso, ¿cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Hay que usar la cláusula GROUP BY:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

La consulta sería:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country as Pais, COUNT(CustomerName) as Clientes
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
```